# Picking healthy ingredients for sandwich in Subway

Tags: nutrition

I eat at Subway pretty frequently. I would like to choose the heathiest ingredients to put inside my sandwich. What are these ingredients? Assume that I am a normal person with no illness like diabetes.

Comment: Yes, assume a standard normal person.

Comment: Define "healthiest."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The American Heart Association, as well as the NIH and others, have [recommendations on eating healthier when eating out.](https://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/HealthyLiving/HealthyEating/DiningOut/Tips-for-Eating-Fast-Food_UCM_308412_Article.jsp)

The fundamentals of what specific foods AND what quantities of those foods make for a "healthy" diet involves a very large discussion that is beyond the scope of this question.

In this specific setting, one way to approach it is to consider the choices between nutrient-dense foods versus calorie-dense foods as ONE measure of "healthy."  For weight management, the number of calories you eat each day are important to consider as well.

[Nutrient-dense foods](https://www.choosemyplate.gov/nutrition-nutrient-density) have more nutrition packed into something with fewer calories - for example spinach, cucumbers, peppers, tomatoes, onions, sprouts...  Olives and avocados have more calories but are still nutrient dense with healthy fats.

Calorie-dense foods include things that have many calories (and often fat) in small amounts of the food, proportionally high in comparison with less nutrition - like mayonnaise, fried foods, sugar, flour/bread, etc.

Examples: Many cheeses and some meats (like salami or tuna with mayo) have more calories and fat per gram of protein and are therefore less nutrient-dense than lean meats (like chicken or turkey breast).  Mustard or vinegar have nearly no calories, whereas Mayonnaise has a lot.

[Subway has a nutrition information webpage](http://www.subway.com/en-us/menunutrition/nutrition) for specific information.